# Rails Polymorphing has_one association redirect_to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, polymorphic-associations

In my app, user is used for the authentication phase, and with a polymorphic has_one association, it will be associated at different type of users, with different actions.

This is the user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  validates :username, presence: true, 
     uniqueness: true
  belongs_to :role, :polymorphic => true, dependent: :destroy
end
```

and this is one of the models associated

```
class Guest < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user, as: :role
end
```

Logging and authentication call home_index_path, and the current user is stored in current_user.

In the Home Controller i have:

```
def index
  if current_user
    redirect_to current_user.role
  else
    render 'unlogged'
  end
end
```

In route.rb i have:

```
resource :guest do
 member do
  get 'dashboard'
 end
end
resolve ('Guest') {[:guest]}
```

Now the problem: assuming that the user is a **guest**, in this way i'm redirected to method `show` of `GuestsController`, but i need that is redirected to method `dashboard`.

How can i do?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on it, please? your question is unclear now.

Comment: Ok, i will reelaborate in another way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've resolved with polymorphing_path

```
redirect_to polymorphic_path([:dashboard, current_user.role])
```

Comment: Remember to mark your own solution as "correct" to close the issue :)

Comment: How can i do that?